# Custom function returns correct results and also undefined. Why is that?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on my JavaScript skills and i wrote that little piece of code:

```
var Intel = ["a", "v", "f", "c", "s"];

if (Intel && Intel.constructor == Array) {
    alert('correct');
} else {
    alert("false");
}

alert(Intel.length);

function showThemAll() {
    // this function will alert every single data of the table

    for (var i = 0; i <= Intel.length; i++) {
        //alert of the data
        alert(Intel[i]);

    }

}

showThemAll();
```

I don't understand though why, with the correct result, I get an undefined alert.

Can you please help me out?

Comment: What do you mean by pleasant result?

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < Intel.length; i++) {`

Comment: @techfoobar i mean the alert of every single data in the Intel array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
i <= Intel.length
```

Arrays are zero index, so you are reading one too many with the `=`

Change it to the following and you will not get the undefined

```
for (var i = 0; i < Intel.length; i++) {
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are running your loop till `i <= Intel.length`.

It should be `i < Intel.length`

Array index start with 0 and hence end with one less than length of the array.